# Prove $\theta$ is a surjective homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Could someone help me to figure it out?I totally have no idea about that. I'd appreciate it.

Recall that $R[x]$ is the ring of polynomials with variable $x$ and coefficients in $R$. Define a function $\theta : R[x] \to R$ by $\theta(f(x)) = f(5)$. Prove that $\theta$ is a surjective homomorphism.

Comment: Let $r\in R$ and let $f(x)=r$ (the constant polynomial equal to $r$). What is $\theta(f)$?

Comment: maybe the professor made a typo?how about f(θ(x))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of $\theta$ is evaluation of a polynomial at 5: take a polynomial $f(x)$, plug in $5$ for $x$, and calculate the result. To be surjective means that for any $y\in R$, there is some polynomial $f(x)$ such that $\theta(f(x)) = f(5) = y$. Given $y$, can we find such a polynomial? Of course, for example the constant polynomial $f(x) = y$. (Among many others.)

Comment: can you give me more specific descripitions about it? Sorry,I do not understand.

Comment: @Bao Can you ask more specifically? Which parts do you and which don't you understand?

Comment: Can you show me a example. Thanks

Comment: Say we have a polynomial $f(x) = x^2 - 4x - 4$, then $\theta(f(x))$, by definition, is $f(5) = 5^2 - 4\cdot 5 - 4 = 1$. Another example: $\theta(x^3 - 100) = 5^3 - 100 = 25$. Now the claim is that $\theta$ is surjective, which means that every real number can come up as a result. For example, is there a polynomial $g(x)$ such that $\theta(g(x)) = 42$? Yes, we have $\theta(8x + 2) = 8\cdot 5 + 2 = 42$. But we could just have said $g(x) = 42$, for then surely $g(5) = 42$! This works for every $y\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: oh！I understand what your mean

Comment: Thanks for your help! I appreciated it!